# Users from customized ssh_users are removen in deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I have a customized `ssh_users` recipe by overriding `customized.rb` in my custom recipes git repository.

There is  weird thing happening. Users are being created, as long as there are no custom recipes added to the deploy event.

Otherwise, the users are created in a setup event, and removed in a configure event completely.

How can I prevent this ? Is it a normal behavior ?

Comment: There is no "ssh_users" cookbook in the community site. Closest would be "ssh_user" but looking at that does not help me understand your question.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor yes there is `ssh_users` in OpsWorks https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/tree/release-chef-11.10/ssh_users